# is this a misdeal?

Tags: live

Tournament style, every player receives a hand whether they are at the table or not(if not present, hand is immediately mucked) hand is dealt, blinds are posted, under the gun calls, plus one calls, next player folds and the next player says he never got a hand. This is confirmed by number of cards in the muck. Does play continue as is or is the hand declared a misdeal?

Comment: similar - guy gets dealt 2 aces, but the dealer throws the next player his next card a little too wild, and it flips. What happens?

Comment: A single exposed card on the initial deal is not a misdeal unless it is one of the first two cards dealt. Dealer should leave the card face up, continue dealing, then replace the exposed card with what would have been the first burn. Two or more exposed cards is a misdeal.

Answer (score 1):

Action continues. It is substantial action, two players have acted on their hands by betting and calling. If the action would of been less, like a couple of players mucked, maybe a misdeal. With a caveat that it could be ruled differently in different venues.

Comment: Agreed. WAY too much action for a misdeal. Players who put money in the pot are entitled to action on the hand.

Answer (score 0):

Action continues because that player had plenty of time to speak up that he didn't get dealt two cards. Alternatively, if it isn't a serious tournament or whatever just deal him the top two cards from the deck because statistically they're just as random as all of the others.

Comment: yeah, they're just as random, but people at the table are likely to Freak Out if you tried that!

Comment: that's why I said if it isn't a serious tournament or whatever. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ask your local casino/tournament director.
Everyone have their own rules about things like that.